# Holomorphic function satisfies estimate

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Determine whether there exist functions $f$ which are holomorphic in a neighborhood of 0 and satisfy
$$n^{-5/2}<|f(1/n)|<2n^{-5/2}$$ for $n\geq 1$. 
What method should you use?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $n\to\infty$ to conclude that $f(0)$ must be $0$. What order can the zero have?

Comment: So you can conclude that $f$ has infinite order of zero at origin?

Comment: @amathnerd A holomorphic function can't have a zero of infinite order.